# Extract three numbers from a long number in code

Tags: c#, asp.net, algorithm, math

I am building my own sharding solution with ASP.NET C# and MySQL. For the Id of each row I use the following:

- Shard Id - Int (1-65535)
- Table Type Id - Small Int (1-65535)
- Incremental number (1 - 4294967295)

So for example, an ID should be in the url like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com/folders/65535655354294967297
```

What I want to know is how to combine the numbers into a big number so I can extract the data later on. So for example, I won't use 1 as the shard ID, I would probably need to you 00001 because later it will be easier to extract that number by making a division on the whole number.

So how can I do that, what is the best way to build a long number with three seperate numerical values and then be able to extract them back in code?

I look for the most **efficient** way to do it in C#

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't put each one in a separate part of the URL, e.g. http://mywebsite.com/folders/65535/65535/4294967297

Comment: yes, to massy, facebook, pinterest and all the big players use a long number, not in folders like, so I just follow the trend, and it looks better in my opinion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hex represantations of numbers

```
ushort ShardId=1;
ushort TableTypeId = 100;
uint IncrementalNumber = 1000;

string url = ShardId.ToString("X4") + TableTypeId.ToString("X4")
                                    + IncrementalNumber.ToString("X8");

var i1 = Convert.ToUInt16(url.Substring(0, 4), 16);
var i2 = Convert.ToUInt16(url.Substring(4, 4), 16);
var i3 = Convert.ToUInt32(url.Substring(8, 8), 16);
```

**OR**

```
string url = (((ulong)ShardId << 48) | ((ulong)TableTypeId << 32) | IncrementalNumber)
             .ToString("X16");

var u  = Convert.ToUInt64(url,16);
var i1 = (ushort)(u >> 48);
var i2 = (ushort)((u >> 32) & 0xffff);
var i3 = (uint)(u & 0xffffffff);
```

Comment: interesting, let me check it. It is effective in terms of performance?

Comment: I need a function that gets a string like this: "00001000020000000015" and returns array of [1, 2, 15] respectively (in the example: 1 is the shard id, 2 is the table type id, and 15 is the incremental). In the above example, the numbers are embedded in the string in their decimal form as you can see)

Answer (score 2):

You pretty much described the answer in your problem. Define a fixed width for each number.

```
int iShardId = 12; // Fixed width of 5
int iTableTypeId = 840; // Fixed width of 5
long lIncremental = 967295; // Fixed width of 10

string sMyId = String.Concat(iShardId.ToString("00000"), iTableTypeId.ToString("00000"), lIncremental.ToString("0000000000"));
```

You can then parse the string later (through an iHttpModule or whatever) using RegEx:

```
RegEx rMyText = new RegEx(@"/(?<shard>[0-9]{5})(?<table>[0-9]{5})(?<inc>[0-9]{10})/?$");
Match mMyValues = rMyText.Match(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);

if (mMyValues.Success) {
    int iShardId = Convert.ToInt32(mMyValues["shard"].Value);
    int iTableTypeId = Convert.ToInt32(mMyValues["table"].Value);
    long lIncremental = Convert.ToInt64(mMyValues["inc"].Value);
}
else {
    //The input didn't match
}
```

The RegEx is intended as a sample to parse the numbers, but obviously depending on how you plan to implement, you should adjust it to make sure that the input is limited to the values you are expecting by using beginning/terminating slashes or end of string ($).

Comment: I saw solution that uses moving bits to the left. So I just wanted to know that this is the best way to do it, and whether I will have problems with it of some kind, something that I am not aware of.

Comment: It's the smartest way to do it. Any efficiencies you can gain by using a binary breakdown will only make your application incredibly complicated for whomever has to work on it next.

Comment: I'd be careful here - having your inputs as `int`/`long` could let someone pass a too-long value, and your `regex` doesn't fail if there are more than 20 digits as there would be in the resulting string, so you'd get different values out.

Comment: The RegEx was meant as an example since I have no clue what the intended purpose is. Obviously this can be easily fixed by adding / to the end and beginning or using $ ^ which IMO is a separate topic.

Comment: I can use try block to catch an error if someone use a very long number that doesn't fit. I think that bit shifting is the most efficient way to do it, don't you think?

Comment: No. You don't need a try block, just check to see if the RegEx matches.

Comment: I didn't want it to get too heavy on the RegEx part, but it seems unavoidable. I updated the sample with a contained test and check for you.

Comment: So it's better to use regex over bit shift ?

Comment: There's nothing in today's technology that is going to yield the slightest difference in performance. The only advantage to using the binary format is making your application look more complicated

Comment: Tumbler used left shift , take a look: http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/10853187575/sharding-ids-at-instagram

Comment: Can you test it against bit shifting in terms of performance, just rung it in a loop and see if it is more efficient, if you can

Comment: Is your site getting as much traffic as Tumblr? I'm going to guess its probably doing a tiny fraction of what Tumblr is. If you really want the fastest solution, then separate the numbers with slashes. Then there's no conversion except string to int or long.

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to use binary numbers and append them together to form a single number.

> - Shard Id - Int (1-65535)
> - Table Type Id - Small Int (1-65535)
> - Incremental number (1 - 4294967295)

The Shard Id and the Table Id both requires 16 bit, and the Incremental number requires 16 bit. This means you can represent the data with 64 bits.

Example:

**Shard Id**

Dec: 7

Bin: 0000 0000 0000 0111

**Table Type Id**

Dec: 2435

Bin: 0000 1001 1000 0011

**Incremental number**

Dec: 23456457

Bin: 0001 0110 0101 1110 1010 1100 1001

**Final number**

Concat the binary values like

Shard id + table type id + incremental number

Bin: 0000 0000 0000 0111 0000 1001 1000 0011 0000 0001 0110 0101 1110 1010 1100 1001

Dec: 1980783105796809

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily complicated, and I'm quite sure that deserializing the value would easily make up for the performance gained in the serialization process.

Comment: I remember Pinterest used bit shifting with their solution, so I thought that bit shifting is the fastest in terms of performance

Comment: If this was 10 years ago or your site is really getting as much traffic as Pinterest, then I'd say it would be worth consideration.

Answer (score 0):

Several options, roughly from longest (most readable?) to shortest (least readable)

- Pad each number with zeroes to the longest it could be (`00001000010000000001`)
- Separate the numbers with hyphens, or even slashes (`1-1-1` or `1/1/1`)
- Combine your two `ushort`s and `uint` into a `ulong` and put *that* in the URL
- Combine the eight bytes into an array, Base64 encode it and put *that* in the URL

I'd go with the second one - it's probably going to be shortest most of the time and is most human-readable.